# QualNet Simulator

Tags: networking, simulation, network-protocols

I have two question about simulation on QulaNet simulator:

1. I want to build a network on ***QualNet*** Simulator, **each node in this network send a  message [application layer message] to other nodes in its range**. I read in the manual there are two types of application layer protocol, one for generating traffic (ex: CBR), and one for application layer routing protocol(ex: BellmanFord), i wonder which type i should follow to apply what i mentioned in the first two lines.
2. I think there is no need to any routing protocol, in the GUI there is a "**None**" choice, but i didn't find the source code of it yet ! Where i can find it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont confuse with Bellmanford and CBR protocols.Bellmanford is a routing protocol but they placed under Application layer for their programming convienience.

CBR is your actual Data traffic so you can see all the statistics related to your data traffic under cbr(client,server).When coming to network routing protocol in QulaNet if you did not configured any routing protocol by default it will take Bellmanford as routing protocol for which you can see the statistics under application layer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. so i must follow application layer protocol steps like CBR, but without client,server .. i.e same code for each node and then work if it is sender or receiver based on my application